# C# to Lambda - count decimal places / first significant decimal

Tags: c#, lambda

Out of curiosity, would there be an equivalent Lambda expression for the following?

... just started using lambda so not familiar yet with methods like zip ...

```
//Pass in a double and return the number of decimal places
//ie. 0.00009 should result in 5

//EDIT: Number of decimal places is good.
//However, what I really want is the position of the first non-zero digit 
//after the decimal place.

int count=0;
while ((int)double_in % 10 ==0)
{
double_in*=10;
count++;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for an extension method which do that ?

Comment: I am not sure why you need a lambda to do that, but naively any expression can be turned into a lamdba using the followinq : `() => { expr }`. Could you add more details on what you expect ?

Comment: What I'd call number of decimal places and what your algorithm calculates is quite different. Your code calculates where the most significant digit is. For example I'd say 0.0123 has 4 decimal digits, but your algorithm would output 2.

Comment: Re comments above:
I could probably write an extension method to do the above... just querying other options though.

Comment: Don't _need_ a lambda to do above. As I said, just out of curiosity. I'm interested in alternatives to the standard loop - a single statement.
'Most significant digit' is possibly a better description, or even 'First significant decimal'. :-)
Eye roll at Will's nothing comment. If you can't say anything constructive, don't say anything at all, genius.

Answer (score 7):

```
 double1.ToString().SkipWhile(c => c!='.').Skip(1).Count()
```

For example:

```
double double1 = 1.06696;
int count = double1.ToString().SkipWhile(c => c!='.').Skip(1).Count(); // count = 5;

double double2 = 16696;
int count2 = double2.ToString().SkipWhile(c => c!='.').Skip(1).Count(); // count = 0;
```

Comment: And what happens if the current culture doesn't use `.` as its decimal separator?

Comment: Then you would just look for the separator according to the culture. Would that be difficult?

Comment: You should rather specify the `InvariantCulture` than trying to parse the formatting of an unknown culture.

Comment: Ok, and what happens when `ToString` produces something like `1.2345E-35`? Are you going to special-case for all the various outcomes of `ToString`?

Comment: Good answer showing possible construct. Nice to see further discussion. :-)

Comment: Finally, how to fix the ToString() with exact 0 decimal? 5126.0 keeping it generic (which means no ToString("0.00")

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.Ceiling(-Math.Log(double_in, 10))
```

Comment: While this does return the same results as the OP's technique, neither of them actually return the number of decimal places. They both work ok when there are all leading zeroes (eg, 0.00009), but fail with numbers like 1.23456, 0.07003 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write an `InfiniteSequence` function like

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns an inifinte sequence of integers starting with 1
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<int> InfiniteSequence() {
  int value = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield return ++value;
  }
}
```

(This kind of infinite enumeration is missing anyway in .NET :) ...)
And then use it like

```
var count = InfiniteSequence().Select(i => (int)(double_in * Math.Power(10,i))).TakeWhile(v=>v%10==0).Count();
```

That would be a direct translation (except for the way the powers of 10 are calculated) of the original code.

Comment: Your `InfiniteSequence` method is functionally identical to `Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

If thought this would more likely answer your question, and is culture invariant.

```
Math.Max(0, num.ToString().Length - Math.Truncate(num).ToString().Length - 1)
```